# Using past tense for present

Tags: verbs

Why do some people say 'Did you know that Earth is much smaller than Saturn? Why not 'Do you know that Earth is much smaller than Saturn?'?

Comment: Because presumably, at the moment you ask the question, the person knows it. But you want to know if they knew it _before_ you asked.

Answer (score 0):

"Did you know that ... " is an idiom. It has an implication beyond asking about somebody's state of knowledge. It often implies something like "this is an interesting piece of information which I think you are probably not aware of, so I can enjoy imparting it to you". But it can have other connotations.